# Deciding the minimum support threshold for the frequent itemset generation in apriori algorithm

Tags: python, data-mining, apriori

I want to find the minimum support threshold for the apriori algorithm.I know its completely user and dataset dependent, but I found an article where an exponential decay function was used. 
http://data-mining.philippe-fournier-viger.com/how-to-auto-adjust-the-minimum-support-threshold-according-to-the-data-size/ 
This is the link where the formula is derived against the apriori algorithm. I want to know how to decide the values for the constants 'a','b' as they can differ on the user's basis as well. Also 'c' is said to be the minimum possible support. I used the inbuilt python `mlxtend` package to generate the frequent itemsets, where `min_support` acts as one of the inputs. So, how do we decide 'c' before using the `apriori` method and henceforth generating the minimum possible support

Answer (score 0):

Having to choose a, b and c is no better than having to choose just over parameter...

I think this equation is meant for adjusting your parameter over time as your data set grows. But it seems you already have found multiple decent parameters to compute a and b.